# Virtocommerce Storefront Core deployment to Azure 500 Error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, virtocommerce

I've deployed from github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-storefront-core to my Azure account, but get the following error when browsing to the storefront site:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>
> .NET Core 4.6.26212.01 X86 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.0.0-rtm-26452    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393    |   Need help?

I've confirmed that the content connection string is correct, the App Id and the secret key.

Looking at the the Log Stream in Azure, it's a 500.0 error and the link that it gives for possible errors/solutions is [to a Microsoft support atticle](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=500,0,0x00000000,14393)
which doesn't provide any Azure information.

I've enabled logging via the Kudu console, and the exception that is being thrown is

```
`Application startup exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at VirtoCommerce.Storefront.Extensions.HostingEnviromentExtension.MapPath(IHostingEnvironment hostEnv, String path) in D:\home\site\repository\VirtoCommerce.Storefront\Extensions\HostingEnviromentExtension.cs:line 12
   at VirtoCommerce.Storefront.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<ConfigureServices>b__5(FileSystemBlobContentOptions options) in D:\home\site\repository\VirtoCommerce.Storefront\Startup.cs:line 134
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions``1.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory``1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager``1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy``1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy``1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy``1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy``1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache``1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func``1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager``1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager``1.get_Value()
   at VirtoCommerce.Storefront.Domain.FileSystemContentBlobProvider..ctor(IOptions``1 options, IMemoryCache memoryCache) in D:\home\site\repository\VirtoCommerce.Storefront\Domain\ContentBlobProviders\FileSystemContentBlobProvider.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor``2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor``2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor``2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor``2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]'
```

Comment: Show me please value of this setting `ContentConnectionString` from appsettng.json

Comment: "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=vcplatformturtle;AccountKey=key-removed;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", which I had to update because the deployment from github left this as the default.

Comment: I just realised where the mistake is - I've used the connection string to the storage account, rather than the connection string from the app settings in the platform config.

Comment: Do you still need help?